# Best way to echo/pass a string array in BASH

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I have function in my shell script which returns an array of strings. Each elem in array may contain embedded whitespace. I need to echo/pass this result (string array) so that consumer should eval it into an array and not consider embedded whitespace inside a string

Something like this

```
function get_prop
{
    prop=$(prop_command $1 $2)
    eval "prop_array=($prop)"
    echo "${prop_array[@]}"
}

props="$(get_prop arg1 arg2)"
for p in $props; do
    do something
done
```

The above doesn't work in case of elem having embedded whitespace, as at the consumer end it will be treated as two elements.

It is worth to mention that my prop_command backquotes the embedding whitespace in individual elem if exist.

for e.g., if my string array has two elems "a b" and "c d"

```
echo $prop
a\ b c\ d
```

What are the other possible ways to handle these type of special cases

Comment: Is there a character that can't occur in the strings?

Comment: Sometimes the method is used to get password also, so it can contain any character.

Comment: set [IFS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs) to only space or linefeed.

Comment: That would still seperate an elem with embedding space right!? That is exactly my challenge

Comment: Including tabs and things like `$'\03'`?

Comment: As I said before, the probability of password containing tabs and $'\03' is nonzero.

Comment: @user3532105 One idea would be to use null as separator. Have a look in this gist : https://gist.github.com/gevasiliou/abe6c8d84924e9ecfb6930ebef9f8fbe